# EconSE twitter is LIVE

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

Hey guys after being given the green light on creating a Twitter Account I took initiative and i made it.

Check it out, follow it and tell your friends!
https://twitter.com/EconomicsSE

Comment: Is it possible, by any chance, to put some pictures in the profile? otherwise the blue is too 'boring'... ;)

Comment: And Thanks John ;)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.